# Google test don't see custom flags

Tags: c++, googletest

Why google test don't set my flag when I type

```
--gtest_email="example@gmail.com" --gtest_passwd="passwd"
```

and here is my code

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
GTEST_DEFINE_string_(email, "example@gmail.com", "Login to authorize to the server");
GTEST_DEFINE_string_(passwd, "passwd", "Password to authorize to the server");

class A: public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    void SetUp() override {
        email = ::testing::FLAGS_gtest_email;
        passwd = ::testing::FLAGS_gtest_passwd;
    }
};

Test_F(A, B) { std::cout << email + " " + passwd << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Or is there another way to parse command line arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other than the known flags with the prefix `--gtest_` are eaten as unrecognized by GoogleTest engine and are not passed to an user code. Use any other names w/o that prefix. Don't use GoogleTest private macro `GTEST_DEFINE_string_`, all macros with the suffix `_`.

Comment: Can you specify what should be used instead? Or is it not possible to have custom flags at all?

Comment: @Curious Use any flag name except starting with `--gtest_`.

Comment: which macro to be used to define a custom flag? You say `Don't use GoogleTest private macro GTEST_DEFINE_string_`. 

Can you edit your answer to add an example please?